# How long is an event with a temporal operator stored in working memory by default?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

Assuming the following when-clausel:

```
$A : AEvent()
$B : BEvent( this before $A )
```

@org.kie.api.definition.type.Expires() is not set on either event object.

What is the default duration BEvent is stored in the working memory, assuming there is no AEvent occurring.

Answer (score 0):

They will be kept in the working memory until you manually retract them.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I did a few experiments and it seems they are retracted after 24h. Is this possible?

Comment: The documentation is not clear about it, but 24h seems arbitrary to me (unless your rules are written in a way that let Drools know that a Fact is no longer needed after 24h)